# DJI N3 N1 flight controller differences

Tags: dji-sdk

I am looking into buying a DJI Matrice 100 for research purposes. I was looking online but I don't seem to find an answer to this.

What are the main differences between the N1 and the N3 flight controller?

Could you tell me if: Both controllers allow for interfacing to the drone through the [DJI SDK and therefore through ROS](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between N1 and N3 is the generalization part.

As far as I know, M100 N1 only allow you to use quad mode. 
N3 allows you have quad octo hex, etc. and N3 can allow simple interface with DJI GO, iOSD, Zenmuse Z15-A7, 5D III, GH4, BMPCC, Ronin-MX, X3, X5, X5R, DJI propulsion systems, S900, S1000, S1000+, etc. where N1 can not.

Secondly, N1 has less option in OSDK setting and less update speed of IMU. The details I quite forgot, But i do remember much lesser option when looking at assistant2 osdk tab

Other things like the simulator, I never tried it before with N3 and N1. therefore I can't comment.

But I do recommend A3 instead of N3 and N1. A3 can allow 400hz IMU update which grants better Visual Inertial or LIDAR Inertial based navigation. It performs exceedingly well when GPS is really bad.

YES N1, N3, A3 all can interface with ROS. that has no issue.

Comment: The N3 also allows IMU updates at 400 Hz. As far as I'm aware, the different between the A3 and N3 is the RTK GPS capability and Triple "industrial-grade" IMU configuration  vs a possible triple IMU configuration on the  on the N3 albeit with a single "industrial-grade" IMU. In my own opinion, the N3 is better value for money if you don't need RTK and that level of redundancy in your system